# Does joint exchangeability imply conditional exchangeability?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2, Y_2)$ be exchangeable, that is,
\begin{align}P((X_1, Y_1)& = (x_1,y_1), (X_2, Y_2)  =(x_2, y_2))\\
 &= P((X_1, Y_1)=(x_2,y_2), (X_2, Y_2)=(x_1,y_1))
\end{align}
 Does it imply that
$$P(X_1 = x_1, X_2=x_2|Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2) = P(X_1=x_2, X_2=x_1|Y_1=y_2, Y_2=y_1)$$